# How to get response status of large list of subdomains?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, aiohttp

I have been trying to check the status of all these subdomains all at once and I have tried multiple techniques even grequests and faster than requests wasn't much helpful and then I started using asyncio with aiohttp and it is slower than normal requests library now. Also I checked that it wasn't actually sending the requests asynchronously rather it was sending one after another.

I know that "await resp.status" has issues because resp.status does not support await but I tried removing it and it's still the same.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

start_time = time.time()


async def main():
#List of 1000 subdomains , Some subdomains do not exist 

    data = [ "LIST OF 1000 SUBDOMAINS" ]

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in data:
            pokemon_url = f'{url}'
            try:
                async with session.get(pokemon_url, ssl=False) as resp:
                    pokemon = await resp.status
               #If subdomain exists then print the status
                    print(pokemon)
            except:
               #else print the subdomain which does not exist or cannot be reached

                print(url)

asyncio.run(main())
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: `for url in data` is a synchronous iteration.

Comment: Actually i tried putting it inside and mapping them then it shows me ```None```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried multiple techniques even grequests

`grequests` works fine for this, you don't have to use async if you don't want.

```py
import grequests
import time

urls = ['https://httpbin.org/delay/4' for _ in range(4)]
# each of these requests take 4 seconds to complete
# serially, these would take at least 16 (4 * 4) seconds to complete

reqs = [grequests.get(url) for url in urls]
start = time.time()
for resp in grequests.imap(reqs, size=4):
    print(resp.status_code)
end = time.time()
print('finished in', round(end-start, 2), 'seconds')
```

```
200
200
200
200
finished in 4.32 seconds
```

Comment: ```finished in 131.82 seconds```

Still its quite slow for large list of subdomains, I tried 100 and it took 131 seconds so if i try 1000 it will be a lot more

Comment: @Jabin You can increase the `size` parameter for increased parallelism. Just don't go overboard. For example if I use `httpbin.org/status/200` for the 100 URLs and use `size=20` I get `finished in 2.19 seconds`

Comment: I actually didn't know about the size parameter that actually solves a lot of my things.

Comment: @Jabin the README for `grequests` explains error handling: https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests